# ResponsiveSlides dose not whork whid PHP echoed content

Tags: php, list, echo, out

I am trying to make work ResponsiveSlides for my image slider. Problem is, that its simply not showing images. The image link works. I don't know. maybe some ideas? It works if i create list manualy ,but not if echoed out.
Scrip

```
  `<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="rslides">
        <?php
            $images = get_images_by_id($_GET['subj']);
            while($image = $images->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo '<li src="images/'. $image['new_name'] . '"></li>';
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

`In browser i get back

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="rslides rslides1">
      <li id="rslides1_s0" class="rslides1_on" src="images/5uldreonzj1k74tfmaigch6vw39spb80q2.jpg" style="display: block; float: left;   position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 2; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;"></li>
      <li id="rslides1_s1" class="" src="images/54ti98jgrw6ndf7vakpou1zqe3b0lmsh2c.jpg" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;"></li>
      <li id="rslides1_s2" class="" src="images/iw5cltnpk783g6jmzbfu1vd24qa9hr0ose.jpg" style="float: none; position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 1; display: list-item; transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0s;"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Relative path? Tried using the browser console to see where the images are being caught?

Comment: _“It works if i create list manualy ,but not if echoed out”_ – well then compare both and find the difference!

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento obviously <li> element don't need src it's <img> tag that that's missing in list. Thanks anyway :)  works now like a charm.

Comment: Delete this question. It's not going to help anyone else.